# Guild Wars 2 LFG Tool Abbreviations

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been playing Guild Wars 2 for years, but it's only within the last couple of days where I actually decided to hook up with others and do some dungeons.

There's a lot I don't understand in the Looking For Group tool, some abbreviations that users post to help people understand what their run of the dungeon will be.

For example, one I saw last night was: `p3 2.5g`

Comment: `p3` would most likely mean `path 3`, but I'm not sure about the other one. Also don't necessarily expect logical or consistent abbreviations. From my experience in MMORPGs, people tend to develop lots of different abbreviations, especially in a game split between many different servers and sub-communities. As such I'd even say this might be off-topic here since you can't get a complete list. You may only try to list the most popular abbreviations, but even those are subject to change depending on which server you are, which time zone, region, etc.

Comment: Path 3 and around 2.5 gold gain would be my guess

Comment: I disagree with this question being closed as too broad. The answer fits the question nicely. The OP isn't asking for a list of all MMO LFG terms.

Comment: I have to agree with @DavidYell. OP is clearly looking for abbreviations specific to the LFG tool in GW2. I've played it since it's release, running dungeons like a maniac and there are really only a handful abbreviations in use, which [Shunwoo's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/194287/78254) cover pretty well.

Comment: This is being marked as too broad because it's not specifically asking about any abbreviations other than p3 2.5g. If there was a specified list, a specific area of abbreviations (classes, areas, pvp, pve) or even a couple of scenarios, it would be a better question. As of the way it's currently worded, it's too broad by just simply asking for abbreviations in general about a game.

Comment: @DavidYell I voted to close as unclear. The question provides **one** *example* unclear abbreviation, while the question indicates that there are more (How many? unknown). The OP may not intend to ask for *all* MMO LFG terms, but as there is only one example with an unknown number of others, it might ask for them all. (Although I will assume based on the tags that it is limited to those used in GW2). Additionally the presence of a good answer does not necessarily make the question not 'too broad', but it would indicate that the question is likely salvageable and can be edited to be acceptable.

Comment: @ChaseC The single example given isn't the subject of the question.

Comment: @TrentHawkins How could this question be edited to make it acceptable? Even though the list is very short, the OP does not know how many abbreviations exist. Would asking for an unofficial list, to the best of the communities ability, still be considered too broad?

Comment: Edits not by the asker should **never** change what the question is asking.  Suggested edits are for cleaning up grammar and making the question clearer, not for altering what the question is about.  I have rolled back the edit for that reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a habit present in the majority of MMO's to make the information readable in one glance.

In this case it means : path 3 of the dungeon, participating costs 2.5 gold

By the way this is against Arena.net politics, the gold is about paying for the dungeon run. 1-2 people that can solo/duo the run offer the last slots of the group at X gold to make profit.

In general in GW2 you can find those abbreviations too :

- **AP**, with for example : 5000AP min. This means 5000 Achievement Points are required to be accepted in the group
- **AR**, with for example 10+ AR. It stands for Agony Resistance, the statistic specific to fractals, and so 10+ means that you need at least 10 in this statistic to be accepted.
- **Zerk** for people requiring full Berserker gear
- **80s** requires people to be at level 80 as some dungeons start being available before level 80
- **Exp** stands for Explorable mode, in opposition to story mode
- **GC** Gearcheck : people will make you link your gear to verify if it meets their requirements

And now in general in MMO's those are really frequent :

- **LFG** : Looking For Group (it can be LFP if you mean Party instead of Group)
- **LFM** : Looking For More (When a group is needing more people) (Credit to DavidYell)
- **Exp** : Experienced (you must know the instance/dungeon already)

(Credit to DavidYell for **LFM** meaning, to Amos M.Carpenter for **80s** abd **Exp** in GW2 and to Daft for **GC**)

Comment: I always read LFM as 'Looking for more' meaning there is a number of players already in the team and they want more people.

Comment: @DavidYell You're totally right, I'm changing that, thanks.

Comment: And of course there's the famous LOL: "Look Out, Lemurs!"

Comment: +1; one more I'd add is "80s", a requirement for participants of a lower-level dungeon to be level 80 to prevent people from using the dungeon to level up. On the other hand, "swapping alts" or similar is sometimes used to indicate that a person will run the dungeon with a level 80 and swap to a lower level alt to get the completion experience (sometimes having another party member watch the final cut scene to give the alt time to enter the dungeon can help). Incidentally, "Exp" is used by some to indicate "explorable mode" as opposed to "story mode", which can lead to confusion.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Thank you I'll add "80s", but "swapping alts" isn't really an abbreviation right ? And for "Exp" I didn't put it in GW2 specific to prevent this confusion ^^

Comment: The OP said "there's a lot I don't understand" in the LFG tool; I took "some abbreviations" to just be an example, but that's up for interpretation of course :-). And yes, "experienced" is the most common meaning of "exp" - I was merely pointing out the possible confusion, not saying you should change that part of your answer.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Well i made a GW2 specific "Exp" and a general case "Exp" to be sure haha.

Comment: I've seen GC. Which usually means a Gear Check. (I hate gear checks)

Comment: @Daft Thank you, I added it, and I actually think GC is ok. Some people have fun by running dungeons casually, normally and some others like doing them to farm or for the challenge of getting the fastest clear. Then GC becomes necessary to find people that share your definition of "having fun" in GW2 :)

Comment: @Shunwoo oh yeah I totally understand why people do it, and I usually run 100% zerk, which is what people wanna see, but for some reason it still bugs me!

Comment: @Daft I haven't seen gear checks since they removed magic find from gear.

Comment: Note: Arenanet is not against selling paths in a dungeon, they are against people exploiting bosses/terrain to reach the final boss (and then selling party slots). If you legitimately solo/duo the dungeon to sell slots, it's fine.